# (Python) How to import from external projects that share same submodule names?

Tags: python, python-3.x

### Setup

Suppose I am making use of two other people's *complex* projects, cloned from Github, called `foo` and `bar`, that both contain subdirectories of the same name. Importantly, `foo` and `bar` are complex and they contain many code that assume their own project structure. Specifically, none of the two projects are setup as a Python package.

As an example, my project structure as well as the structure of the external projects is:

```
project_root/
    myprog.py
    external/
        foo/
            models/
            ... # other code that involve `import models...`
        bar/
            models/
            ... # other code that involve `import models...`
```

where `external/foo` and `external/bar` are essentially git submodules for my own project.

In particular, both `foo` and `bar` have other code that may contain something like:

```
import models.some_model.some_stuff  
...
```

(note that even if the above code appear in subdirectories of `foo` or `bar`, it is still ok for that project, because, for example, their intended usage involves loading the project's path into `sys.paths`)

### My Question

Let's say I am coding my `myprog.py`. I know that if all I want to do is to import a module from `foo`, I could:

1. Create a symbolic link to the `foo` project under `project_root` directory
2. Add path to `external/foo` into my `sys.path`, like so

   ```
   # myprog.py
   import sys
   sys.path.append("absolute/path/to/external/foo")
   ```

The first step allows me to do:

```
# myprog.py
from foo import ...
```

while the second step essentially preserves the validity of `foo`'s own code with `import models...` because now `models` is part of my `sys.path`.

However, **how to do this when there are two external projects that share the same submodule names**?

Because of name conflict, if I add the path to both projects into my `sys.path`, then it is ambiguous what `import models` means and will break the external projects' code.

I hope my question is clear. I think there must be a way to do this as people are reusing other people's code all the time.

Comment: I guess you have to use `import x as y` at some point.

Comment: I guess so, but in the external projects' code, they don't do that. I wonder if what I am asking for is supported in Python at all.

Comment: The question is, how would you import `foo` or `bar`? Don't reach into the depth of their project and import only the piece you want. Access them from their top level where they differ. `import foo.modules as foo_modules` or something similar. The modules themselves should be using relative imports for submodules so those shouldn't conflict.

Comment: @Axes319 I will give that a try. The thing is the imports inside those external projects are not relative imports.

Comment: That would cause an issue if the file you're importing has an import that is not a relative import. It would seem like those projects would then be intended to be run as standalone projects and wouldn't be suitable as such without some modification.

Comment: Do you mind sharing the projects in question and what is attempting to be imported?

Comment: @Axe319 I can message you about that. Isn't it a loss if those complex-code cannot be used externally? One thing I am missing is the use of `importlib`. I have not used it at all but it might be helpful in this situation I wonder.

Comment: @Axes319 I actually don't have enough reputation for that. One project is https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5. Does that help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236901/discussion-between-axe319-and-zkytony).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by ensuring **ordering** when I import from the external projects. Essentially, when I need to use the submodules in `foo`, I do

```
sys.path.insert(0, "path/to/external/foo")
```

and later when I use the submodules from `bar`, I do

```
sys.path.insert(0, "path/to/external/bar")
```

This means the import statements for `foo` and `bar` should not appear at the top of the file, but dynamically as they are needed. Python is still very flexible!